# How to identify a USB device given its VID and PID

Tags: usb

In the Windows Device Manager, I can look up the VID and PID of each USB device connected to my system.  What is a good way to look up the vendor of the device using this information?

My motivation is that I want to deploy an application to my users that will identify all USB devices connected to their systems.

Comment: For now, it will be sufficient if I can look up this data on the web, but it would be nice if there were some automated way of looking up the vendor for each device on a list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's just one of those things you have to keep an updated list on, although having slightly outdated information wouldn't be terrible, since the most popular vendors have been around forever.  [Here's](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids) one source you could use that appears to be regularly updated.

Comment: Thanks. The top of that site links to a user interface, https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/ Which was all I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this source it is what I use and it seems to be always up to date and very easy to use [pcidatabase](http://www.devicekb.com/drivers) and it is an online search so you don't have to look through a list of numbers.

Comment: Malwarebytes blocked that site due to spyware.